# Unix Bash Script Create Directory parent and child method

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create directory using if condition statement, while running script i am not able to find any expected result from the script, but when i am running manually only mkdir command alone its creating as we expected; here the sample code.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_path=/tmp/opt/app/software/{A,B,C,D}

if [[ -d  $dir_path ]]; then
            mkdir -p /tmp/opt/app/software/{A,B,C,D}
fi
```

can you please advise, how we can create this..

Answer (score 5):

`dir_path` is a "list" of directory paths due to the `{}` parameter expansion.  If you write this out:

```
dir_path=/tmp/opt/app/software/A /tmp/opt/app/software/B /tmp/opt/app/software/C /tmp/opt/app/software/D
```

This is what's being used in the `test` of the `if` statement.

Either you want to iterate over the list of sub directories, or just pass them to mkdir.  mkdir simply won't create the directory if it already exists.

Your `mkdir` command actually expands out to:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/opt/app/software/A /tmp/opt/app/software/B /tmp/opt/app/software/C /tmp/opt/app/software/D
```

If you want to itterate and still do a check (which while needless in this example can still be useful other times.)

```
# Declare the variable `dirs` to be an array and use
# parameter expansion to populate it
declare -a dirs=(/tmp/opt/app/software/{A,B,C,D});

# Iterate over the array of directory names
for dir in ${dirs[@]}; do
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        # The directory does not exsist
        mkdir -p "$dir";  # Make the directory
    fi
done
```